# Lower supply voltage LED status indication

Tags: voltage, led

I have implemented the circuit as shown in attached image for 2.1V status LED indication. But after turning OFF VCC_2V(=+2.1V) while VCC_5V(=+5V) ON condition, LED is not turning OFF immediately. Can anyone please correct the circuit implementation?

[image]

Comment: Are you pulling the 2v output low or turning it off as in high impedance?

Comment: +2V is the external power supply and I a turning it OFF.

Comment: Off then probably means the gate is left floating.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor on the gate of the mosfet stays charged when you disconnect V_CC_2V. Add a high value "bleeder" resistor from the gate to ground.

Comment: Assuming the output is pulled low instead of left hi-z, wouldn't that already be the case?

Comment: yes, it would..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. As per ONSEMI recommendation I placed weak pull down resistor of 100K and 10K between Gate and Source. After placing these resistors, LED is turning OFF-----> ON----->OFF within 3 seconds.

Comment: Can you show us a schematic of the circuit that drives the gate?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the graph in the [NTA4153 data sheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NTA4153N-D.PDF): -

[image]

- With a \$\color{purple}{\boxed{\text{2.0 V}}}\$ \$V_{GS}\$ drive, that voltage has to collapse a long way before the LED starts to switch off. Typically this might need to fall to a voltage as low as 0.9 volts.
- With a \$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{1.4 V}}}\$ \$V_{GS}\$ drive, the MOSFET will still be drawing around 20 mA and a typical LED will still be bright.

How much lower could \$V_{GS}\$ go before the MOSFET shows sign of adequately turning off the LED?

You might want to consider using a potential divider from the 2 volts input to the gate in order to put the gate at a lower voltage. Of course, just open circuiting the 2 volt line will leave the MOSFET gate charged up and it would remain on indefinitely but, with a potential divider at least the lower resistor would discharge the voltage.

Or use a comparator if you need accurate results.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for the response and support. How much should I make the Gate voltage by following voltage divider? As per ONSEMI recommendation I placed weak pull down resistor of 100K and 10K between Gate and Source. After placing these resistors, LED is turning OFF-----> ON----->OFF within 3 seconds.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Isn't the source at ground in your circuit? So, the pull down resistor is between the gate and ground, and the 10K is also between gate and ground? Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @SrikanthKacchu if you need better accuracy, use a comparator.

Comment: @Math Keeps Me Busy, Source is connected ground itself. I placed 10K or 100K(One at a time) resistor between Gate and Source(GND).